# Is there any react native package which auto crops image like instagram when we upload image?

Tags: ios, reactjs, image, react-native, image-processing

I want to crop image like instagram, when user upload either single or multiple image I need to crop image automatically like instagram, is there any package in react-native?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) package for cropping your image. You just need to define `height` and `width` like:

```js
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  width: 300,
  height: 400,
  cropping: true
}).then(image => {
  console.log(image);
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Yes but it is not working for multiple image and this is not auto crop, it gives UI to user to crop image manually.